# Where do you pass Environment variable in Cloud Run API

Tags: google-cloud-platform

In the cloud run you can pass environment variables like following

[image]

how do i pass these in the cloud run API?

https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.locations.services

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are familiar with Kubernetes, you have to notice the environment variable are corelated with the container run in the Pod.

With Cloud Run, it's the same. With the API, you deploy a revision. So, go to the [RevisionTemplate](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.locations.services#RevisionTemplate), then to the [container](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest/v2/Container) (it's a list, only one is possible now, but several containers will be accepted in a near future).

From the container, you can see the "env" object that allows you to reference your env vars.